# Eclipse Android SDK: Can't access layouts after adding 2nd activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout, android-activity

I'm very new to Android and Java developing. So far, everything worked pretty well. But i keep failing adding a 2nd activity and accessing its layout elements.
I used the manifest.xml wizard and file->new->other->android activity. This works well, adds a new java file and layout. Starting the activity works also pretty well.

My problem is that i can't access any elements of the new layout. When i try to create a button via "findViewById(R.id.?)" it shows elements that don't exist on the layout, but the elements on my layout are not shown. It seems that a layout from a previous project is used.

Additionaly the eclipse editor shows a warnining in a line above:
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondactivity);`
"activity_secondactivity cannot be resolved or is not a field".

This warning is not there until i type "R.id." and even if i delete it, it won't disappear.

In all tutorials on the web and youtube it seems to work so fine, i was trying different things for two days and can't figure it out. I would be very happy if anyone could help me out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you imported the right "R" (yourpackage.R) and not android.R. For example, if your package name is com.my.package, then you have to import com.my.package.R. And try clean your project (Project->Clean).